# Splitting equation made of NSString with NSRegularExpression and finding left side of Equation

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I have a string such as below in my application:

```
    b=c+32
```

I parse the string using below code snippet to split it to b,=,c,+,32. That works fine. However I need to know which variable is left side of the "=" operator. This variable always comes first in the expression. Is there a way in NSRegularExpressions to give me index of the results so I can compare them to see what's left side of "=". If there's a better match that would give me the first element I would settle for that too.

Here's the code to split them.

```
     NSString * textpattern = @"[A-Za-z]+";
     NSString * numberpattern = @"[0-9]+";
     NSString * opPattern = @"[-+/*]";
     NSString * copPattern = @"=";


    NSRegularExpression * reg = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: @"(\\d+\\.\\d+)|(\\d+)|([a-z])|([+-/*=///^])|([/(/)])" options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *matches = [ reg matchesInString: exp
                                     options: 0
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [exp length])];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        NSString* text = [exp substringWithRange:[match range]];

     NSMutableDictionary *term = [NSMutableDictionary new];


     if ([text doesMatchRegStringExp:textpattern])
    {
        NSLog(@"variable");


        [term setObject:@"variable" forKey:@"name"];


    }
    else if ([text doesMatchRegStringExp:numberpattern])
    {
        NSLog(@"number");


        [term setObject:@"number" forKey:@"name"];


    }
    else if ([text doesMatchRegStringExp:opPattern])
    {
        NSLog(@"op");

        [term setObject:@"op" forKey:@"name"];


    }
    else if ([text doesMatchRegStringExp:copPattern])
    {
        NSLog(@"cop");


        [term setObject:@"cop" forKey:@"name"];


    }
    else
    {


        [term setObject:@"other" forKey:@"name"];

    }

        }




//  NSString+RegExpExtensions.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (RegExpExtensions)
- (BOOL)doesMatchRegStringExp:(NSString *)string;

@end

#import "NSString+RegExpExtensions.h"

@implementation NSString (RegExpExtensions)
- (BOOL)doesMatchRegStringExp:(NSString *)string {
    NSPredicate *regExpPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", string];
    return [regExpPredicate evaluateWithObject:self];
}
@end
```

Thank you.

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you are trying to do. Why don't you state the problem you're trying to solve in clear, concise terms? Then we might be able to help.

Comment: Hi Duncan, I edited the question. Please let me know if it makes more sense now. I apologize for previous ambiguity.

Comment: You can use regex to lex, but not to parse a mathematical expression. NSRegularExpression, which uses ICU regex library, doesn't have power to do so.